# SQL Server query to replace text in column

Tags: sql-server, join

I have some tables in my database.

First is `Employees` which consists of `EmployeedId` (PK), `Name`, `Email`, `ContactNo`, `password`, `salary`, and `employeestatus` (`FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Status(id)` )

Second table is `Address` which has columns

```
AddressId (PK), Id (FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId), 
Addressstatus (FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CheckListAction(id)), EmployeeAddress
```

`CheckListAction` has `id` (PK) and `value` (YES, NO, N/A)

`Status` has `id` (pk) and `value` (A for active, I for inactive, W for waiting)

Now I have created a grid which shows the data from the `Employees` and `Address` tables. This is the query used:

```
SELECT
    e.name, e.email, e.contactno, 
    a.employeeaddress, e.salary, e.empployeestatus
FROM 
    Employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Address a
WHERE
    a.addressstatus = 1
```

Now my grid shows employeestatus as A,I, or W. The user does not know what A,I or W means so I want to show the full name to user that is ACTIVE,INACTIVE OR WAITING. So how do I modify the above query that shows me the full name instead of just letters.

Comment: The best solution would be to add another column to the `CheckListAction` and `Status` tables with the names you want to display, and include these in the query. Otherwise you'll have to modify the query every time you add an new row to those tables

Comment: It looks like more a front-end problem than a database problem. On the DB side, you can easily solve this with `CASE` or creating a domain table for the status. Depending on your stack you can even use Enums in the Business Layer

Comment: Could you also show the Status table?

Comment: My status table consists of only two columns(id and value). Id consists of A,I and W. Value consists of Active,Inactive and Waiting

Answer (score 1):

You should do some reading on CASE as jean suggested. Here's the Microsoft page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Here's my quick solution:

```
SELECT
    e.name, e.email, e.contactno, 
    a.employeeaddress, e.salary,
    CASE e.empployeestatus
    WHEN 'A' THEN 'ACTIVE'
    WHEN 'I' THEN 'INACTIVE'
    WHEN 'W' THEN 'WAITING'
    END
FROM 
    Employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Address a
WHERE
    a.addressstatus = 1
```

Comment: I dont want to do this using case or enum. My status table has pk id which is referenced to my employeestatus in Employees table. So how can i do this using simple join and by picking their id's?